# reading JSON from file and extract the keys returns attribute str has no keys

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am new to Python (and JSON) so apologies of this is obvious to you.

I pull some data from an API using the following code

```
import requests
import json
   
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'accept-encoding':'identity'}
api_url = api_url_base+api_token+api_request #variables removed for security

response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)
data=response.json()
keys=data.keys

if response.status_code == 200:
    print(data["message"], "saving to file...")
    print("Found the following keys:")
    print(keys)
    with open('vulns.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(response.content.decode('utf-8'),outfile)
    print("File Saved.")
else:
    print('The site returned a', response.status_code, 'error')
```

this works, I get some data returned and I am able to write the file.

I am trying to change what's returned form a short format to a long format and to check its working I need to see the keys, I was trying to do this offline using the written file (as practice for reading JSON from files).

I wrote these few lines (taken from this site https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-print-the-keys-of-a-dictionary-in-python)

import json

with open('vulns.json') as json_file:
data=json.load(json_file)

print(data)
keys=list(data.keys())
print(keys)

Unfortunately, whenever I run this it returns this error

```
Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print(keys)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'keys' is not defined
>>> & C:/Users/xxxx/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python.exe c:/Temp/read-vulnfile.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    & C:/Users/xxxx/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python.exe c:/Temp/read-vulnfile.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> exit()
PS C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\scripts\Python> & C:/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python.exe c:/Temp/read-vulnfile.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Temp\read-vulnfile.py", line 6, in <module>
    keys=list(data.keys)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

The Print(data) command returns what looks like JSON, this is the opening line:

> {"count": 1000, "message": "Vulnerabilities found: 1000", "data":
> [{"...

I cant show the content it's sensitive.

1. why is this looking at a str object rather than a dictionary?
2. how do I read JSON back into a dictionary please?

Comment: Just before calling `data.keys` put `print(data)`. What does it say?

Comment: Also, you should use `data.keys()` if that was a dict.

Comment: changing list(data,keys) to list(data.keys()) has removed the error re keys not being defined, but it still refers to str having no attribute keys `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Temp\read-vulnfile.py", line 7, in <module>
    keys=list(data.keys())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'` - I've amended the question with the change to list(data.keys()) and added as much of the output of the file as I can. It is quite big and quite sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have that content stored in file as a string. Just open the `vulns.json` in some editor and there most likely is something like `"{'count': 1000, ...` instead of `{"count": 1000, ...`.

It's opened by `json.load`, but translated to string (see [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders) table).

So you should take one step back and take a look what happens during saving to file. You take some content from your response, but dump the string decoded value into a file. Take instead a try with

```py
json.dump(response.json(), outfile)
```

(or just use `data` variable you already have provided).

This should allow you to succesfully dump and load data as a dict.

Comment: Thank you this worked, not with the output I expected (or wanted) but it still worked and I've marked the answer as such.